# How does a campaign member create date affect the opportunities associated?

Tags: opportunity, campaign

We're in the process of associating contacts with old campaigns but I'm unsure of this scenario:

- Campaign is created in January 2018
- Contact X is added to that campaign as a campaign member in December 2018
- Contact X had an opportunity close in June of 2018

I'm assuming in this scenario the campaign does not get credit for that opportunity closing since the campaign member create date is December 2018.

They would only get credit if they were added to the campaign prior to the opportunity closing.

Is this the right assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure [Campaign Influence](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=campaigns_influence_setup.htm&type=5) to select if these campaigns are influential or not. Note that this works by comparing the CampaignMember created date to the Opportunity created date. So if the Opportunity was created earlier then the CampaignMember, then you're right, it would not have an Influence. You can still specify whatever campaign you want in the Primary Campaign Source field, though.